# Apply qcut to columns of dataframe with user defined percentile values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes, that looks like below.

```
dataframe1 = 

Index  features  constant
0      AA        0.25
1      AB        0.45
2      AC        0.78
3      AD        0.91
4      AE        0.12

dataframe2 = 

Index   AA    AB    AC    AD   AE
0       10    45    15    14   98
1       14    55    55    48   70
2       25    75    87    46   91
3       47    87    25    71   10
4       47    65    58    48   12
5       18    45    69    73   5
```

now by doing -->>

```
qcut(dataframe2['AA'],5,labels = list(range(1,6)))
```

I can get the bins depending on the min, percentile(0.2), percentile(0.4), percentile(0.6), percentile(0.8) and max.

But I want to know whether I can apply qcut on user-defined percentiles.

say the bins for a particular feature should be like below.

```
bin1 = (min)                                      -to-  percentile(constant + ((1-constant)*0.2))
bin2 = percentile(constant + ((1-constant)*0.2))  -to-  percentile(constant + ((1-constant)*0.4))
bin3 = percentile(constant + ((1-constant)*0.4))  -to-  percentile(constant + ((1-constant)*0.6))
bin4 = percentile(constant + ((1-constant)*0.6))  -to-  percentile(constant + ((1-constant)*0.8))
bin5 = percentile(constant + ((1-constant)*0.8))  -to-  (max)
```

Hope you understand.
Need help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the percentiles to `qcut`

```
percentiles = [0, constant + ((1-constant)*0.2), constant + ((1-constant)*0.4), constant + ((1-constant)*0.6), constant + ((1-constant)*0.8), 1]

qcut(dataframe2['AA'], percentiles)
```

Assuming all your values are vaild percentiles, ie between (0,1)